# NodeJS custom shared library

Tags: javascript, node.js, shared-libraries

For Windows Apps I can include a custom module of encapsulated functions like this...

```
(function () {        
        WinJS.Namespace.define("workers");
        workers.f1 = function(arg,arg) { return 1; };
        workers.f2 = function(arg,arg) { return 2; };
})();
```

Then from code call those functions like this...

```
let one=workers.f1('a','b');
```

How is this achieved in nodejs? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I refined the question.

Comment: That's a definite improvement.  To make it even better, could you explain what techniques you've researched or tried?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, you want to use some object that contains functions. There is different ways to achieve that with Javascript and node.

First, with pure javascript, you can define an object `workers`, that contains your two functions `f1` and `f2`

```
// main.js
const workers = {
    f1 (arg1, arg2) {
        return 1
    },
    f2 (arg1, arg2) {
        return 2
    }
}

let one = workers.f1('a','b')
```

If you want to separate your code and be able to create reusable modules, you can also do this with node:

```
// main.js
const workers = require('./workers')

let one = workers.f1('a', 'b')

// workers.js
const workers = {
    f1 (arg1, arg2) {
        return 1
    },
    f2 (arg1, arg2) {
        return 2
    }
}

module.exports = workers
```

As you can see, the use of `module.exports` in your module file enables you to export an object from your file that you will `require()` in any other file.

I hope this helps

You can read the NodeJS documentation about modules, it should also help you: https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html

Comment: Thank you. I was able to achieve a working result without using "module.exports". Is there a benefit to using "module.exports"?

Comment: Yes, there is. The code you provided in your answer does indeed work, but if I'm right, you won't be able to require other modules in your module.js. `module.exports` allows you to control exactly what object or functions you want to expose to the rest of your app.

Comment: Even in an example, "module" is a terrible name for a module.  Perhaps "workers" as in the original?

Answer (score 0):

File "workers.js"

```
{ 
this.foo=function() { return "Hello"; }
}
```

Use in code:

```
let workers=require("../workers.js");
console.log(workers.foo());
```